# Understanding State of JS in Drupal

Tags: 8, javascript

I have a simple contributed module that I have written. It has pretty basic javascript. I decided to clean it up and write it in vanilla js, removing jQuery since that seems to be the direction we're going. Here is the resulting code...

```
const viewSourceLinks = document.querySelectorAll(
  '.simple-styleguide--view-sourecode'
);

[].forEach.call(viewSourceLinks, el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});

const calculableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.calculate');

[].forEach.call(calculableElements, el => {
  const measuredElement = el.querySelector('.measure');
  const info = el.querySelector('.info');
  const lineHeight = `<label>line-height:</label> ${
    window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).lineHeight
  }`;
  const fontSize = `<label>font-size:</label> ${
    window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).fontSize
  }`;
  const margins = `<label>margin:</label> ${
    window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginBottom
  }
        ${window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginRight} ${
    window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginBottom
  } ${window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginLeft}`;

  info.innerHTML = `${fontSize}<br/>${lineHeight}<br/>${margins}`;
});
```

My question is, is this ok? Is this good enough to include as is? In general, it seems the advice is to **always** add your javascript within attached behaviors.

However, once I go down that road, I'm pretty much having to include jQuery in the wrapper. And I would much rather just have vanilla javascript.

The resulting code with behaviors ends up being something like this...

```
(($, Drupal) => {
  Drupal.behaviors.simpleStyleguide = {
    attach(context) {

      const viewSourceLinks = context.querySelectorAll(
        '.simple-styleguide--view-sourecode'
      );

      [].forEach.call(viewSourceLinks, el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          el.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
        });
      });

      const calculableElements = context.querySelectorAll('.calculate');

      [].forEach.call(calculableElements, el => {
        const measuredElement = el.querySelector('.measure');
        const info = el.querySelector('.info');
        const lineHeight = `<label>line-height:</label> ${
          window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).lineHeight
        }`;
        const fontSize = `<label>font-size:</label> ${
          window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).fontSize
        }`;
        const margins = `<label>margin:</label> ${
          window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginBottom
        }
              ${window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginRight} ${
          window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginBottom
        } ${window.getComputedStyle(measuredElement).marginLeft}`;

        info.innerHTML = `${fontSize}<br/>${lineHeight}<br/>${margins}`;
      });

    },
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I've also read that if you have BigPipe enabled, you have to include jQuery. Not sure if that's true or not.

The vanilla js code above seems to be working. I just want to know that I'm doing this right, and that I'm not violating some Drupal standard by not wrapping it in a behavior.

*Note: I should mention there is no ajax behavior in this module. If there were, perhaps I would have to use behaviors and context.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best practice is still to use Drupal's behaviors system even when not relying on jQuery. See [Drupal 8 Drupal.behaviors without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51412962/9637665) for reference.

That said, I think you're on the right path. I find jQuery just slows down the page load when vanilla JS will usually do the trick. That's just my opinion and there's a lot of debate out there.